# How to get colour name from HEX/Integer in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, colors

I get pixel colour from image in android and I want to display the name of that colour to user.
I'm getting hexa value from integer:

```
Palette p = Palette.from(bitmap).generate();
Integer color =  p.getDominantColor(23);
String hex =  Integer.toHexString(color);
infoTV.setTextColor(color+(-16777216));
Integer c = color+(-16777216);
Integer dfs = Color.parseColor(hex);
```

if I parse color I get "unknown color" error

Answer (score 2):

Try Color class method:

```
public static int parseColor (String colorString)
```

**Exmple :**

```
textView.textColor = Color.parseColor("#FF0000");
```

Comment: I'm getting hex value from string:
     Palette p = Palette.from(bitmap).generate();
       Integer color =  p.getDominantColor(23);
      String hex =  Integer.toHexString(color);
      Integer c = color+(-16777216);
       Integer dfs = Color.parseColor(hex);
and it's throwing error on last line of code of  "unknown Color"

Comment: I think you get image color like this int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);  int redValue = Color.red(pixel);int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel); int greenValue = Color.green(pixel); and then covert rgb to hex